# Forking Greenlets

Tags: python, fork, greenlets

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious (and it is a Friday), but is there a way to do the equivalent of an `os.fork()` on a greenlet? I'm not necessarily looking to fork the process, I'm looking to take the greenlet and run one set of code, then another, but with independent scopes (as with `os.fork()`).

Any ideas or should I just get some sleep?

Comment: It would be great if this were possible. It might not even be that difficult from a systems perspective: you could just copy over the `locals()` from each stack frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to conceptually fork a greenlet, just create another greenlet wrapping your "child function". I also highly recommend [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/), which is built on greenlet. The gevent code has a fork() method, but it forks the Python process and then restarts gevent in the child. I bet that you can implement whatever you are doing in gevent with more readable code than just greenlet.